# Access static variable from another class in React-Native app?

Tags: javascript, function, class, react-native

in my react-native app I currently have a User class in which I define a current user as below:

```
class User {
    static currentUser = null;

    //other relevant code here

    static getCurrentUser() {
        return currentUser;
    }
}

export default User;
```

In a different class, I am trying to access the set value of this currentUser. I cannot figure out how to correctly call this function; I am getting the error `User.getCurrentUser is not a function`. Should I be calling this function in a different way?

```
var User = require('./User');

getInitialState: function() {

    var user = User.getCurrentUser();

    return {
        user: user
    };


},
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are mixing `import` / `export` styles. You should either change your import to

```
var User = require('./User').default
```

or

```
import User from './User'
```

Or change your export:

```
module.exports = User
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you also forgot the ***this*** keyword for returning the static "currentUser" field:

```
class User {
  constructor() {}

  static currentUser = {
    uname: 'xxx',
    firstname: 'first',
    lastname: 'last'
  };

  static getCurrentUser() {
    return this.currentUser;
  }
}

console.log(User.getCurrentUser());
```

Comment: For static variables "this" is not a valid source. In this case User.currentUser is the right format.

Answer (score 0):

Try arrow function:

```
class User {
    static currentUser = null;

    static getCurrentUser = () => {
        return currentUser;
    }
}
export default User;
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.