# How can i call static variables from outside of my Component?

Tags: reactjs

I want to create my static variables outside of my component and then call and using it in my component.
Btw i dont want outside variables as a component or props.

Comment: const variableName = [];like this you can use and access in your component ,you can use array objet or string any thing assign to your varibale

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access static variable from another class in React-Native app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517822/access-static-variable-from-another-class-in-react-native-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create class like that

```
export default class TableConst {
  static LocaleText = {
    values: {
      to: "-",
      page: " ",
    }
  };
 }
```

Then import that static class and use it in your main page

```
 import TableConst from "../TableConst";
 ...
 ...
 ...
 let columnDefs={TableConst.LocaleText.values}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you define variable inside the class using a static keyword you can access those variable using class Name directly without instantiating it.

```
class CustomVariables {
   static MyVariable = 'SomeContent';
   static MyVariable2 = 'SomeContent2';
}

export default CustomVariables;
```

Also you could write those variables within the class and return an instance of the class

```
class CustomVariables {
   constructor() {
       this.MyVariable = 'SomeContent';
       this.MyVariable2 = 'SomeContent2';
   }
}

export default CustomVariables();
```

and you can use it like below for both the caes

```
import CustomVariables from 'path/to/CustomVariables';

console.log(CustomVariables.MyVariable)
```