# How can I work with globals in react-native without using the global scope or redux?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am building a react-native application where just about everything in the application is determined by a json file that is pulled from the backend. The large json config object is modified by an external application so it would be read only within the context of the react-native app. I originally was planning on storing it in the redux state but realized that was silly as it will never be modified. I considered storing it in the global state but this feels dirty and not advised. Now i'm thinking of creating a service and storing it there but I'm not sure if that is the best way either. Practically every component will need full access to this large json object so my question is how I store/access this in a proper way that avoids performance issues, unneeded boilerplate, and dangerous code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use static class variable like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517822/access-static-variable-from-another-class-in-react-native-app). But please do **remember** to make sure that **no other codes** is **changing** the value of the static variable other than the part where you load it from backend.

Basically, this answer doesn't really care about performance issue, and dangerous code. So, please someone else check about those points required. Sorry for not helping much.